# Zend framewirk session data get changing and displaying other user data not the logged user data

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

if someone can help with zend returning data from wrong user

Our current problem is when multiple users use our zend application it frequently returning data from other users to another curently loged user,. ie it is mixing users data. We have tried reinstaling the PC, changing browsers, disabling caching..., nothing helped.

Any help apreciated

Comment: Can you show us how you handle the session ?

Answer (score 0):

In zend 2 you can use container, and whenever user has logged in and you want track his session you can do this as following:

```
$loggedUser = new Container('user');
$loggedUser->loggedIn = true;
var_dump($loggedUser->loggedIn); //will print true
```

In case you want to track guest session, simply you can use new different Container for it

```
$guest = new Container('guest');
$guest->visited = true;
var_dump($guest->visited); //will print true
```

also you can use offsetGet, offsetSet instead of setting variables directly

```
$guest = new Container('guest');
$guest->offesetSet('visited') = true;
var_dump($guest->offsetGet('visited'));
```